# Route is not calling the action

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework3, zend-framework-routing

I'm new to Zend-Framework3.

And migrating my ZF2 application to ZF3.

`[:/action]` is not calling the `Actions` in the controller.
Do we have to manually write all actions which are defined in the controller as a route?

Here is router from my `module.config.php`

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'user' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/user[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id' => '[0-9]+'
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => Controller\UserController::class,
                    'action' => 'login'
                )
            )
        ),
    )
)
```

When I try to call `/user/register` action. It generates `404 error`.

Where am I wrong? Or do I have to register all actions manually?

Comment: I think that you can't have "[/:action][/:id]"  router doesn't know which to call... try with [/:action[/:id]]

Comment: Thanks for responding, but it's Not working. I think I have problem in calling the child routes.

Comment: It's not a child route. it's a dynamic route. And probably the problem is regex in action. can you try to remove "constraints" key?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `[a-zA-Z]` with `[a-zA-Z]{1}`?